# Looking for a horror movie with a Wheelchair on fire

Tags: story-identification, horror

I am not sure if my question can fit in the horror-fantasy genre.
I remember seeing a horror movie at the theater in the early 80s. It was in English and in color. The only scene that I remember, I believe it was at the end.

It was a night scene where an evil shape was sitting in a wheelchair on fire breaking and leaping out of a window followed by a crash. I have in my mind a horrid cry and the thing on fire rolling the void of the night.

By the way, the movie is not The Changeling (1980).

That scene has been haunting me for all of these years. Does it ring any bell?

Comment: The novel Red Dragon by Thomas Harris includes a victim being bound to a wheelchair, set on fire, and pushed into a roll, maybe down a hill or ramp. The novel has been filmed, but I do not know if it includes this scene.

Comment: Red Dragon is a remake of the 1986 Michael Mann-directed book adaptation called Manhunter.  That scene is in this film too.

Comment: [Manhunter scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHuNBH7fdYQ)

Comment: [Red Dragon version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpzJ-AUVnl0)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are no listed sci-fi/fantasy aspects.

Comment: Thanks @OrganicMarble and Dosco Jones but it's not Red Dragon or Manhunter. It was a night scene and the wheelchair fly (came out with high speed) from a high window near the rooftop of a mansion or house. It was early 80s when I started college.